# Parsing a string using getInputString()

Tags: java, android

I am creating an android program that reads the result of 'top' command and then computes the CPU usage of the device. I use the following code to get the first line from the 'top' command.

```
java.lang.Process p = null;
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top -d 1");
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while (returnString == null || returnString.contentEquals("")) {
             returnString = in.readLine();
             }
```

I wish to read the third line of the 'top' command. What changes should I make to the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a counter variable to be able to check how many lines have been read. Increment the counter variable everytime readLine is used. Add a condition to your loop to check the limit of your counter (3) and that you didn't reach the end of Buffer reader.